# how to merge group rows in dataframe based on differences between datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I have a `dataframe` with contains events on each row, with a `Start` and `End` `datatime`.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Value' : [1.,2.,3.], 
'Start' : [datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0),datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,1,0),datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,4,0)], 
'End' : [datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,59),datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,5,0),datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,6,00)]},
index=[0,1,2])

df
Out[7]: 
                  End               Start  Value
0 2017-01-01 00:00:59 2017-01-01 00:00:00    1.0
1 2017-01-01 00:05:00 2017-01-01 00:01:00    2.0
2 2017-01-01 00:07:00 2017-01-01 00:06:00    3.0
```

I would like to group consecutive rows where the the differences between `End` and `Start` of consecutive rows is smaller than a given `timedelta`.
e.g. here for a timedelta of 5 seconds I would like to group row with index `0,1` and with timedelta of 2 minutes it should yield in rows `0,1,2`

A solution would be to compare consecutive rows with their shifted version using `.shift()`, however, I would need to iterate the comparison multiple times if groups of more than 2 rows need to be merged.

As my df is very large, this is not an option.

Comment: Maybe its just me but I have no idea what output your are looking for

Comment: show your expected out put ./_\.

Comment: sorry guys it's late :( I am adding the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threshold = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)                                                  
df['delta'] = df['End'] - df['Start']                                                      
df['group'] = (df['delta'] - df['delta'].shift(-1) <= threshold).cumsum()                  
groups = df.groupby('group')
```

Answer (score 1):

i assume you try to aggregate based on time difference.

```
marker = 60
df = df.assign(diff=df.apply(lambda row:(row.End - row.Start).total_seconds() <= marker, axis=1))

for g in df.groupby('diff'):
   print g[1]


                  End               Start  Value   diff
1 2017-01-01 00:05:00 2017-01-01 00:01:00    2.0  False
2 2017-01-01 00:06:00 2017-01-01 00:04:00    3.0  False
                  End      Start  Value  diff
0 2017-01-01 00:00:59 2017-01-01    1.0  True
```